# Extract part of path within XPath to show the extracted values' parent - child relationship

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I need to extract data from the following XML:

```
<Parents>
  <Parent id="1" parentname="Bob">
    <Children>
      <Child id="1" name="kid1" />
      <Child id="2" name="kid2" />
      <Child id="3" name="kid3" />
    </Children>
  </Parent>
  <Parent id="2" parentname="Karen">
    <Children>
      <Child id="4" name="kid4" />
      <Child id="5" name="kid5" />
      <Child id="6" name="kid6" />
    </Children>
  </Parent>
</Parents>
```

And am looking to extract not only the names of all the children, but also which parent that specific child belonged to.

So I would like to be able to extract something that allowed me to know, for example:

- `kid1` belonged to `Bob`
- `kid6` belonged to `Karen`

Or, in tabular format:

```
Parent:  Child:
Bob      kid1
Bob      kid2
Bob      kid3
Karen    kid4
Karen    kid5
Karen    kid6
```

I know I can extract each of these separate data elements fairly simply using XPaths along the lines of:

```
Parents = "/Parents/Parent/@parentname"
Children = "/Parents/Parent/Children/Child/@name"
```

But is there any way to extract them both at the same time so I can know the parent/child relationship without having to create multiple XPaths for each parent possibility?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for` loop to iterate through all `Child` nodes keeping the reference to the current `Parent` node:

```
for $p in Parents/Parent
return $p/Children/Child/concat("parent: ", $p/@parentname, "; child: ", @name)
```

The output:

```
parent: Bob; child: kid1
parent: Bob; child: kid2
parent: Bob; child: kid3
parent: Karen; child: kid4
parent: Karen; child: kid5
parent: Karen; child: kid6
```

---

You may adjust `concat()` function arguments per your needs.
You can check this approach here https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: I had zero clue you could do variable naming / looping like this within XPath! - Just awesome new knowledge! - Thank you!!!

Comment: @JohnBustos, you're welcome. I should have mentioned that `for` loop is XPath 2.0 feature

Comment: Thanks, I did notice that... Seems very few XPath tools allow for using it, but I need it for my .Net code anyways. Got to see how it works there. Thanks again as it is exactly what I wanted!